# Different publisher polling for transaction than the one started

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1-hr1

We have `fully scaled architecture` with 6 CM servers and 6 publisher servers. **On publisher only publisher and transport services are running**.

Recently, we came across a strange scenario where `one publisher rendered the publish package.` After some time we received the failure for the publishing transaction and examining the logs the we found out the `failure was for polling notification and strange part was it was logged in different publisher than the one that performed the render operation.`

In which scenario, publisher switch / failover will happen? Any help in this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to identify the scenario:

We use the approach of publishing in phased manner in which rendering is scheduled 4 hours before going live and at the time to go live, just deployment happens. In this particular scenario, rendering is done by one publisher however tracking of deployment is done by some other publisher.

This scenario creates problem with deleting the xml status files (inside ../tridion/bin/transaction) from publisher that did rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the publishing filters are identical in for publisher (Rendering) and publisher (deploying) in the queue settings in the SDL Management Console?

Comment: yes, same settings for rendering and deploying queue.